# How to determine the correctness of patch application on Weblogic 12c(12.1.0.3.0)?

Tags: patch, middleware, weblogic12c

After applying some PSU patches for Oracle Weblogic12c, what is the correct way to get the details of the patches applied? Some of the analysis is as below:

**=>** **Current Weblogic version = 12.1.3.0.0

=> Applied PSU patches for 21370953 and 22248372, which says its should be version as 12.1.3.0.5.**

The only way that I got to know the patch status is:
***opatch lsinventory*** or ***optch lspatches***.

What are the other ways to get the exact weblogic version with all the PSU patches & what are the process that needs to be followed after patches application?

Comment: **Edit1:** _opatch apply_ completed with opatch success & opatch lsinventory showing all the applied patches in output. Jar files in the **MW_HOME** is updated & showing new timestamp & application deployed showing the changes reflected as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opacth lsinventory is the best to achieve this.
Each Weblogic server instance will log its version (including PSU) when it starts.
You can also check the version with the following java code (inside and ejb, a war, an ear) :

```
import weblogic.common.internal.VersionInfo
VersionInfo serverVersion = VersionInfo.theOne();
serverVersion.getImplementationVersion()
```

You can also use JMX (via WLST for instance) and get the info from the server configuration mbean.
After applying a patch you should always remove these diectories from all your domains and all your servers :

- ${DOMAIN_HOME}/servers//tmp
- ${DOMAIN_HOME}/servers//cache
- ${DOMAIN_HOME}/servers//stage

Comment: This is great to use lsinventory but some of the blogs say that we also get the version information in server logs. I applied path on 12.1.3.0.0 and after the path the version should be listed as 12.1.3.0.5. I checked the same in logs and that is still giving 12.1.3.0.0. I want to know whether this is true for weblogic 12.1.3.0.0 also & logs should show 12.1.3.0.5?

Comment: the logs will not show 12.1.3.0.5 but 12.1.3.0.0 followed by all aplied patches